# Mixing Wolfram Language & WolframAlpha Queries - How robust is it?

Tags: core-language, wolfram-alpha-queries, wolfram-cloud, language-design, natural-language

The advent of *Mathematica* in the cloud and linguistic input potentially transforms expectations of the Wolfram Language's programming model and its inherent robustness. An example of this comes form trying to bridge what seems to be a disconnect in the language between its *Mathematica* and *WolframAlpha* invocations. Consider `CountryData` where up until 2008 you can find the GDP of the US in *Mathematica* :

```
CountryData["UnitedStates", {"GDP", 2008}]
```

[image]

but surprisingly not thereafter (The great recession was bad - but surely not that catastrophic) :

```
CountryData["UnitedStates", {"GDP", 2009}]

(* Missing["NotAvailable"] *)
```

In *WolframAlpha* however, GDP *is* available for 2009 (reassuringly, life continued) as can be seen by typing "US GDP in 2009" into its web page before receiving back a raft of other information. This can be accessed within *Mathematica* where in particular, the GDP information can be zeroed in via the `"Result"` argument:

```
 WolframAlpha["US GDP in 2009", "Result"]
```

[image]

Now you can integrate this functionality by doing an apriori check on this data's availability within *Mathematica* and then redefining `CountryData` to grab it from *WolframAlpha* if necessary.

```
SetAttributes[CheckCountryData, HoldAll];

CheckCountryData[CountryData["UnitedStates", {"GDP", yr_}]] := 
With[{temp = CountryData["UnitedStates", {"GDP", yr}]},
 If[Head@temp === Missing,
      Unprotect@CountryData;
      CountryData["UnitedStates", {"GDP", yr}] := 
      WolframAlpha[yr // StringTemplate["US GDP in `1`"], "Result"];
      Protect@CountryData,
      temp]
    ];

CheckCountryData[CountryData["UnitedStates", {"GDP", #}]] & /@Range[2008,2020];

Table[{
  yr // StringTemplate["US GDP in `1`"], 
     With[{yr = yr}, 
  Defer@CountryData["UnitedStates", {"GDP", yr}]], 
  CountryData["UnitedStates", {"GDP", yr}]},
      {yr, 2008, 2020}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Now maybe `CountryData` will be updated in *Mathematica* and/or the two data sources more tightly integrated at some point but the broader point remains; consider how the programming model has been changed along with the language's robustness, reliability and repeatability. The input/output/complexity/programming experience is now more fluid depending, for example, on the constancy/consistency of linguistic interpretations; the speed/availability of cloud connections, the date,  W/A compatibility etc.

Note that instead of a `WolframAlpha` call, *Free-Form* input followed by its `Entity` interpretation can be used

[image]

and while this perhaps improves the interpreting consistency it is also less concise and less amenable for ready parametrization (e.g. used for a range of years instead of only 2009).

One part of *Mathematica*'s programming language morphing into an expanded *Wolfram Language* seems to incorporate an ether-like presence, an interoperability (including with natural language) but I'm wondering if anyone has successfully/unsuccessfully integrated *Free-Form* input and/or widespread `Entity`/`WolframAlpha` calls in any significant way?

Comment: Have you tried raising a query with WRI support?  Might be useful to get the official answer.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an official answer when it comes to the interplay between natural language and programming languages but yes the `CountryData` lagging is probably worth flagging. Unfortunately, though this data curation issue is a much wider challenge since a pretty significant percentage of calls are in fact `Missing[NotAvailable]` (particularly non-US data) which I suspect reflects current priorities/curation limitations.

Comment: A major issue with substituting in W|A data for Country data seems to be ensuring Apples are Apples.  eg WolframAlpha["US GDP in 2008","Result"]  <> CountryData["UnitedStates",{"GDP",2008}].  1.46 tn vs 1.4 tn

Comment: I raised the missing country data as an issue with WRI and its been passed onto to the devs. Will wait and see...